# How to conditionally project fields during aggregation in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a question documents like.

```
[
 {
   type:"general",
   viewers:[
           {userId:"1", viewedAt:"10 Aug"},
           {userId:"2", viewedAt:"12 Aug"}
           ] 
 },

 {
   type:"programming",
   viewers:[
            {userId:"3", viewedAt:"1 Aug"},
            {userId:"2", viewedAt:"19 Aug"}
           ]
 }
]
```

And the expected result add additional field called `viewed` is:

if given `userId` suppose `userId:1` is in viewers list then add `viewed:true`

else `viewed:false` as follows :

```
[
 {
   "type":"general",
   "viewed":"true"
 },
 {
   "type":"general",
   "viewed":"false"
 }
]
```

I tried this code but showing error:

```
Question.aggregate([
  {
  $project:{
    type:1,
    viewed:{
       $cond:[
         {$viewedBy:{"userId":1}},"true","false"
       ]
     }
  }
}
])
```

P.S : I slightly updated my question, objects in viewers has multiple key-value pairs. i.e `userID`, `viewedAt`, `filledAt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/in/) aggregation expression in 3.4.

```
Question.aggregate([
  {
   $project:{
    type:1,
    viewed:{
       $cond:[ {$in:[{userId:"1"}, "$viewers"]},"true","false"]
    }
  }
 }
])
```

OR

```
Question.aggregate([
  {
   $project:{
    type:1,
    viewed:{
       $cond:[ {$in:["1", "$viewers.userId"]},"true","false"]
    }
  }
 }
])
```

Comment: it works if the object inside array has single key-value pair. But suppose if the viewer filed has multiple fields like `viewers:[{"userId":"1","viewedAt":"12 Aug" } , {"userId":"3","viewedAt":"10 Aug" }]`